# Slash in IRI (SPARQL)

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl

I have a IRI that has a slash in the IRI:

Example triple

```
:name/name1 :hasCity :City.
```

I want to find all names that have the slash in them.

I've tried the query:

```
select ?name {?name ?pred ?obj FILTER regex(str(?name),"/")}
```

This gives me all names even if they don't have a /

The I tried:

```
select ?name {?name ?pred ?obj FILTER regex(str(?name),"//")}
```

this also gives me all names including ones that don't have a /

The I tried:

```
select ?name {?name ?pred ?obj FILTER regex(str(?name),"\/")}
```

for that I get the error: Bad escape sequence in a short double-quoted string at '"\'

Is there a right way to get the ones with "/" only in the part after the IRI prefix?

Followup question: Is there a way to query those names without sparql throwing an error?

Comment: Short IRIs that start with ":" get expanded to full IRIs by appending the default namespace in front of them. In most cases the namespace already contains "/" characters (http:// or file:/) and therefore your regex will match any such IRI.

Comment: BTW "/" is a forward slash (or just slash) not backslash.

Comment: @DRSK: Do you mean slash `/` or backslash `\`? If you really mean slash `/`, this will not work for URIs as they usually contain already slashes after the protocol definition. Otherwise, please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @CaptSolo, @AKSW; can't believe I made the mistake. So, is there a way to get all subjects that have the slash in the part after the prefix?

Comment: RDF data only has full IRIs – the short form (`:name/name1`)  is expanded using the default namespace. The result might be, for example, `http://server/path/more/path/name/name1`. Now, it might contain many slashes. It is up to you how to construct a regex that matches what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most "typical" IRIs will already have at least two slashes in them (e.g., in **http://**), but not all IRIs are like that (e.g., **urn:ex:foo**), so there's not going to be a universal way to do this.  However, if you're mostly using "typical" IRIs, then you can just use a regular expression that looks for a slash after the double slashes, like **"//.*/"**.  For example:

```sql
select ?name {
  values ?name { <urn:ex:foo>             #-- no slash, but won't match
                 <http://example.org>     #-- no slash
                 <http://example.org/foo> #-- a slash
               }
  filter regex(str(?name), "//.*/")
}
```

```
 ----------------------------
| name                     |
============================
| <http://example.org/foo> |
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

> Example triple
>
> ```
> :name/name1 :hasCity :City.
> ```
>
> I've tried the query:
>
> ```
> select ?name {?name ?pred ?obj FILTER regex(str(?name),"/")}
> ```
>
> This gives me all names even if they don't have a /

This answer is almost certainly correct, but it isn't obvious because you're looking at abbreviated names.

Try the following:

```
 select (str(?name) as ?fullname) {?name ?pred ?obj FILTER regex(str(?name),"/")}
```

That will ensure that the name of the object is displayed as seen by the regex. My guess is that all your objects have URIs starting `http://` or similar, and they'll obviously match.

Comment: The query you've give me still gives me all names (as you've noted) since there is a // in the http. How can I get names(i.e. after the URL) that have a slash?

Comment: There's no right answer, really, because there's no general function that takes a URI and returns a short name. One simple match is `[^/]/[^/]` (i.e. lone slash neighboured by non-slashes).

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the slash with a backslash, for example:

```
PREFIX mdb: <http://example.org/movieDB/>
PREFIX country: <http://example.org/movieDB/country/>
BASE <http://example.org/movieDB/>
construct {
    ?s ?p ?o
} 
where {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    ?s mdb:country mdb:country\/France .
}
```